Shell: Customizing the "Display all N possibilities? (y or n)" message
I already know that double-pressing the Tab key on Bash terminal will enlist all files and folders in the current working directory or, when appropriate, show Linux executables that I can run. I want to add custom text into the "Display all N possibilities?" message and simplify "(y or n)" into "[y/n]". Even nicer, I want to colorize the message so that I can make my console's interface look more sleek.
How can I customize it?

This seems to be hardcoded in libreadline (complete.c) so unless bash has some other means, your only option should be to patch it...

@frostschutz With the links and possibly quotations of the relevant code, this should be made into an answer.
